# Changing url from JavaScript code and adding another value

Tags: php, javascript, url

I have following mysql query:

```
$colname_profile = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
  $colname_profile = $_GET['user'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_profile = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_profile, "int"));
$profile = mysql_query($query_profile, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_profile = mysql_fetch_assoc($profile);
$totalRows_profile = mysql_num_rows($profile);
```

and following JS part of code I need to change:

```
url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".profile_history_results:last").attr("uh_id"),
```

now, how do I add another value inside JS code from above query which should be in format of

```
user='.$row_profile['user_id'].'
```

so I need to keep whats already inside that JS url and at the end add that user ID. In case you need complete JS here it is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){
                $('#loadmorebutton').html('<img src="../images/body/icons/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".profile_history_results:last").attr("uh_id"),
                        success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                    $("#historywrapper").append(html);
                $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More');
                }else{
            $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe change url line to something like this:

```
url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".profile_history_results:last").attr("uh_id") + "&user=<?php echo urlencode($row_profile['user_id']); ?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way the question is asked, this will work:

```
url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".profile_history_results:last").attr("uh_id") + "user=<?php echo $row_profile['user_id']; ?>",
```

However I don't know if that is what you are looking for. Is `$row_profile['user_id']` only a single value on a page or is this like a list of users and for each row in the table is there a different `$row_profile['user_id']` that might exist? If this is a single value, for example the user_id of the user visiting the page and you want to pass that along with every ajax request, you might be better off storing that value is sessions elsewhere as it is unlikely to change unless the user logs out and back in under another account.

Comment: this is a single value and your suggested code worked perfectly, thanks